# vs code not recognizing php code inside html

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, xampp

As you can see that my php code is showing error and is not been recognized by the vs code.My separate .php file is running smoothly but i cannot write php code inside html.I am using xampp, linux, vs code.

The code:

> myphp.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

<form method="POST" action="myphp.php">

    Name : <input type="text" name="name">

    <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameEmp; ?></span>

    <br>

    E-mail : <input type="text" name="email">

    <br>

    Link : <input type="text" name="link">

    <br>

    Comment : <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>

    Gender :

    <input type=" radio" name="gender" value="female">Female

    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">male

    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

</body

</html>
```

editor:
[image: editor screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please show the image on the question. Please follow community guidelines or search for `how to ask questions on stackoverflow`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have written the correct syntax for php but for php to work you have to change the file extension to .php rather than .html

Comment: Is there no way around it? Why can you write CSS inside <style> and JavaScript inside <script>? Somewhere in VS code, it needs to be set up to work with HTML, CSS and JS when editing .html-files, so the functionality has to be there.